# Porque é que é correto dizer "círculo vicioso" mas não "ciclo vicioso"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões

Numa das minhas leituras online, deparei-me com uma constatação de que realmente não fazia ideia, e que me deixou intrigado: que quando nos referimos à cadeia de eventos que degradam uma coisa ou situação de forma recorrente, não está correto dizer **"ciclo vicioso"**, mas sim **"círculo vicioso"**. (Toda esta pergunta também pode ser aplicada para a versão "positiva": "ciclo virtuoso" e "círculo virtuoso")

Uma pesquisa rápida leva-me a esta pergunta no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/ciclo-vicioso-ou-circulo-vicioso/2227), com a seguinte resposta:

> A expressão correcta é «círculo vicioso».
>
> De acordo com alguns dicionários, esta expressão designa uma sucessão, geralmente ininterrupta, de acontecimentos que se repetem e voltam sempre ao ponto de origem, colidindo sempre com o mesmo obstáculo.
>
> Na doutrina de Aristóteles, esta expressão designa uma falha lógica que consiste em alcançar dedutivamente uma proposição por meio de outra que, por sua vez, não pode ser demonstrada senão através da primeira.
>
> Por conseguinte, faz todo o sentido que a expressão seja círculo, uma vez que as situações se vão repetindo sucessivamente, provocando um impasse, isto é, A dá origem a B e, por sua vez, B dá novamente origem a A. Assim, não se sai do círculo!
>
> A palavra ciclo, por sua vez, designa uma sucessão de fenómenos sistematicamente reproduzidos em períodos regulares.

Há certas partes da resposta das quais eu não concordo: nada na definição de [ciclo (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ciclo) implica que a sucessão de eventos seja reproduzida em períodos regulares, nem que os eventos do respetivo ciclo sejam independentes (ou seja, que apenas ocorram de forma "sistemática" por outros critérios), podendo muito bem se sucederem por dependência de eventos anteriores. Para além disso, não vejo qualquer definição de [círculo (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%ADrculo) que referira uma sucessão de objetos ciclicamente dependentes. Até se pensarmos na definição matemática, uma circunferência (porque só esta é que faria sentido, e é a mesma usada na analogia da resposta acima) é uma composição de pontos que são definidos como estando à mesma distância do centro. Não existem dependências entre pontos, e um ponto não se define de forma recorrente a outro ponto (sem pensar em fórmulas equivalentes que não são causa para a definição original).

Para além disto, soube que na língua inglesa, tanto a expressão [*"vicious circle"*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vicious+circle) como [*"vicious cycle"*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vicious+cycle) são aceites como sinónimos.

Portanto, qual será mesmo o motivo para se considerar incorreto dizer "ciclo vicioso" em português correto?

Comment: Muito interessante: acho que tenho andado a falar "incorretamente", então. A definição do Aristóteles é a de um raciocínio circular, logo aí justifica-se que seja círculo e não ciclo. Mas atualmente creio que o termo se usa mais a propósito de fenómenos que se reforçam mutuamente. Por exemplo, quebra na procura (demanda); as empresas vendem menos e despedem; baixa o rendimento, logo a procura volta a diminuir. Aqui *ciclo* não me parece mal.

Comment: Em um ciclo já há a previsão de que coisas aconteçam numa sequência lógica, assim, mesmo que se volte ao começo ao final do ciclo, não há vício pois foi programado ou era esperado que tal fato ocorresse. Ele é finito. Vai de A->B->A. Se for pra começar de novo vai de A->B->A. E no círculo vicioso a sequência deveria ser interrompida para se sair do círculo e não se cometer o erro (vício), mas o círculo não tem fim e tudo ocorre de novo. Vai de A->B->A->B->A->...

Comment: @AndréLyra Eu conheço (e uso) esta expressão como uma série de acontecimentos que ocorrem, sim, numa sequência lógica, como nos fenômenos que o Jacinto citou. Vêm-me à cabeça os ciclos de melhoria contínua (que são infinitos), e os ciclos termodinâmicos (presumidamente infinitos), e os ciclos de oferta e demanda que regulam a economia capitalista.

Comment: "Há certas partes da resposta [do Ciberdúvidas] com as quais eu não concordo". Eu acho a resposta um disparate pegado. Parece-me que aconteceu o seguinte: a respondente sabe que apenas *círculo vicioso* vem nos dicionários, e que é a expressão original; vai daí, põe-se a inventar argumentos para "demonstrar" que *ciclo vicioso* não faz sentido. Ainda que esses argumentos fossem válidos, dado que o significado relevante original de vicioso é 'defeituoso, errado', nem mesmo *círculo vicioso* faria sentido: >>

Comment: >> *raciocínio vicioso* é um raciocínio errado;  e originalmente chamou-se *círculo vicioso* a um tipo particular de raciocínio vicioso, o raciocínio circular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para mim, *ciclo vicioso* é correto nos contextos em que é habitualmente usado. Não é a expressão original, mas os falantes têm o direito de inventar nomes novos para conceitos antigos, e *ciclo vicioso* assenta que nem uma luva ao conceito que designa. A correção de uma expressão pode ser uma questão de opinião. Portanto vou começar com o que consegui apurar de objetivo:

1. ***Círculo vicioso* é a expressão original** e vem pelo menos já do latim moderno *circulus vitiosus*. A expressão latina está atestada em 1597 [(Ciberdúvidas, 2015)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-circulo-vicioso-e-nao-ciclo-vicioso/33313) e é muito comum nos séculos seguintes [(Google Books)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=circulus%20vitiosus&num=50&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_max:1800&tbm=bks&ei=dmuvWPjFCYjqasfVs9AD&start=0&sa=N&dpr=1). O significado original é ‘raciocínio circular’. Do latim, passou a várias línguas vernáculas europeias, tendo em várias rapidamente adquirido o segundo sentido de encadeamento de fenómenos (exemplos dos dois significados mais abaixo). Em português encontramo-la no Google Books no sentido de raciocínio circular a partir de 1822¹ e no sentido de encadeamento de fenómenos a partir de 1847.²
2. ***Ciclo vicioso* é bem mais recente**. Só aparece no Google Books em 1945.³ Parece ser usado apenas no sentido de encadeamento de fenómenos; nunca no de raciocínio circular.
3. ***Ciclo vicioso* é mais recente, mas tornou-se parte da língua**. No Google geral *ciclo vicioso* é quase tão frequente como *círculo vicioso* (398 contra 435 milhares); o [Corpus do Português—Web](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/web-dial/) apresenta proporção parecida (1499 contra 1601). No Google Books a frequência relativa de *ciclo vicioso* é menor, mas ainda assim muito significativa:

   ```
    Anos              1822-99   1900-44   1945-69   1970-89   1990-99  2000-17
    Círculo vicioso     125        48        40        45        70      277
    Ciclo vicioso         0         0        19        33        42      122
   ```
4. Mas **os Dicionários registam apenas *círculo vicioso***. Procurei nos vários dicionários online, no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) e no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001); todos trazem *círculo vicioso*, nenhum traz *ciclo vicioso*.

A situação na língua inglesa é parecida. A frequência relativa de *vicious cycle* no Google Books é apenas ligeiramente superior ao observado no português (ver [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vicious%20circle%2Cvicious%20cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvicious%20circle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvicious%20cycle%3B%2Cc0), já observado na resposta do Centaurus), e não tenho conhecimento de dicionários que tenham um verbete para *vicious cycle*. No entanto, alguns mencionam no verbete *vicious circle* a existência da variante *vicious cycle* no sentido, tal como se observa no português, de cadeia de fenómenos. (Ver artigo na [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/01/vicious-etymology.html) ou discussão no [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vicious%20circle).)

A meu ver, a razão da preferência dos dicionários por *círculo* é histórica—*círculo vicioso* é a expressão original. No entanto não vejo que esta razão invalide *ciclo vicioso*, e parece-me até questionável a sua completa omissão nos dicionários de português e alguns de inglês, dada a presença significativa da expressão nestas línguas já desde há algumas décadas.

Ademais, *ciclo* é uma boa metáfora no caso da cadeia de fenómenos; mais sugestiva até que *círculo*. Nestes casos, nós temos um fenómeno A que causa o fenómeno B que por sua vez causa A, que volta a causar B, e assim repetindo-se sem fim à vista a cadeia (que pode ter mais de dois fenómenos), perpetuando ou até agravando o problema. Por exemplo, quebra no rendimento das famílias leva a uma redução da procura (que é o que os portugueses chamam à *demanda* dos brasileiros), que leva à quebra na produção e aumento do desemprego, que por sua vez leva a nova quebra no rendimento das famílias, e assim continuamente. *Ciclo* transmite melhor do que *círculo* esta ideia de repetição interminável. Veja-se um dos significados de [*ciclo* no Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=ciclo), que se aplica por exemplo aos ciclos do carbono, fósforo e nitrogénio, explicados mais abaixo no mesmo verbete:

> **2** Sequência de ações, fatos ou fenômenos constituintes de um processo periódico que, partindo de um ponto inicial, acabam por desembocar em um ponto-final que nada mais é que o retorno a esse ponto inicial e consequente recomeço.

Se a esta definição acrescentarmos que a sequência de fenómenos é indesejável, obtemos a definição de *ciclo vicioso* no sentido de cadeia de fenómenos.

Procurei e encontrei várias pessoas a afirmar que *ciclo vicioso* é errado. Curiosamente só uma delas, Gonçalo Neves no [Ciberdúvidas (2016)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-circulo-vicioso-e-nao-ciclo-vicioso/33313), destaca o argumento histórico; todas as outras argumentam principal [(a linguista Sandra Tavares na *Voz do Cidadão*, 2014; após o minuto 8)](http://www.rtp.pt/play/p1781/e195224/voz-do-cidadao) ou exclusivamente [(Mambos da Língua, Rádio Nacional de Angola, em colaboração com o Ciberdúvidas, 2014)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqCerDGLF8E&feature=youtu.be), que *ciclo* é uma metáfora inapropriada. A argumentação é deplorável. Ou focam apenas aceções de *ciclo* que não funcionam (‘período, época’, como em *ciclo do ouro* ou *ciclo das grandes navegações*), ignorando a que funciona (a 2 do Michaelis); ou definem *círculo* e *ciclo* e imputam-lhe conotações muito à maneira deles para demonstrar que *círculo* está correto e *ciclo*, errado. Gonçalo Neves também caracteriza *ciclo* muito idiossincraticamente (que um ciclo “se caracteriza por alternância e progresso”). E mesmo que a sua caracterização estivesse correta, os seus argumentos só se aplicam à noção de raciocínio circular; ele ignora o sentido “cadeia de fenómenos”, que é o único a que *ciclo vicioso* tem sido aplicado.

Por outro lado, o argumento histórico não invalida *ciclo vicioso*. Um falante tem o direito de cunhar nomes novos para coisas antigas. Vejamos um exemplo de raciocínio circular:

> Ana:—“Três é o número perfeito; logo o triângulo, que tem três lados, é a forma perfeita.”
>
> Bela:—“Porque é que três é o número perfeito?”
>
> Ana:—“Então, se o triângulo, que tem três lados, é a forma perfeita, três é o número perfeito”.

*Ciclo vicioso* não é habitualmente usado para estas situações, nem me parece que resulte bem. Mas muitos portugueses nem sabem que *círculo vicioso* se aplica aqui (eu não sabia) e diriam que o argumento da Ana é uma [pescadinha de rabo na boca (foto no Tripadvisor)](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g189158-d8462896-i145033649-Covense-Lisbon_Lisbon_District_Central_Portugal.html). Alguém pode dizer que isso seria um erro? É simplesmente uma nova metáfora (ou talvez seja antiga, sei lá eu), e muito sugestiva. Do mesmo modo, *ciclo vicioso* é uma nova metáfora, e muito sugestiva no sentido em que é usada, e é uma boa alternativa à metáfora original *círculo vicioso*.

Uma diferença em relação a *pescadinha de rabo na boca* é a semelhança entre as palavras *ciclo* e *círculo*, que permite pensar que *ciclo vicioso* apareceu devido a confusão. É o que afirmam Sandra Tavares e Gonçalo Neves. Mas não nos explicam como é que o sabem, nem como é que isso invalidaria *ciclo vicioso*. Se me mostrassem que *ciclo vicioso* não faz sentido, eu dar-lhes-ia ouvidos (eles tentam fazê-lo, mas falham). Mas *ciclo vicioso* faz sentido e é uma metáfora muito sugestiva para o fim com que é habitualmente usada. Provavelmente, essa é a razão ou uma das razões por que vingou. Então use-a quem quiser, e deixem quem quiser criticar.

---

Notas:
**¹** [Vicente José Ferreira Cardozo da Costa, *Que he o codigo civil*, Lisboa, 1822, p. 137](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-IM2AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA137&dq=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBi9XI24bSAhWInRoKHS5PAH04pgQQ6AEIvgIwKg#v=onepage&q=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&f=false); periódico mensal [*O Padre Amaro*, Junho de 1825, p. 138.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KggYAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA138&dq=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBi9XI24bSAhWInRoKHS5PAH04pgQQ6AEItwIwKQ#v=onepage&q=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&f=false), “he girar sempre no circulo vicioso *de sim por que sim, não por que não*”.
**²** [*Revista Universal Lisbonense*, Tomo VI, 1847, p. 86, 122, 458, 498](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qQ8XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA458&dq=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp4KbcvpDSAhVLmBoKHZx5Baw4pgQQ6AEIkQIwJA#v=onepage&q=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&f=false); [Anónimo, *A Questão Vinhateira do Douro*, Porto, 1849, p. 13, 22, 30, 223](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aEY1AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA318&dq=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBi9XI24bSAhWInRoKHS5PAH04pgQQ6AEImQIwJQ#v=onepage&q=%22c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%22&f=false), “enquanto o numerário girar no circulo vicioso d’agiotagem” (p. 223).
**³** [*Fenação*, Brasil, 1945, p. 46](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22Observa-se%20um%20ciclo%20vicioso%20muito%20interessante%22&oq=%22Observa-se%20um%20ciclo%20vicioso%20muito%20interessante%22&gs_l=serp.3...5014.8665.0.9153.3.3.0.0.0.0.77.224.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.f7pSX9y_FHQ): “Observa-se um ciclo vicioso muito interessante. Alega-se que não há produção porque não se conta com meios de transporte. [[Excerto 2]](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22n%C3%A3o%20aumentam%20as%20suas%20linhas%20e%20n%C3%A3o%20melhoram%20o%20seu%22&oq=%22n%C3%A3o%20aumentam%20as%20suas%20linhas%20e%20n%C3%A3o%20melhoram%20o%20seu%22&gs_l=serp.3...8819.12145.0.12503.2.2.0.0.0.0.87.159.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.PKYCicnLpfE) De outra parte, as estradas de ferro argumentam que não aumentam as suas linhas e não melhoram o seu material porque não há o que transportar.” [*Anais do Instituto de Medicina Tropical* de 1952](https://books.google.pt/books?id=r_gOAQAAIAAJ&q=%22ciclo%20vicioso%22&dq=%22ciclo%20vicioso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwnN-V44bSAhVJiRoKHRKnAHs4yAEQ6AEIMzAE).

Comment: @Ramon, obrigado pelas correções. Algumas delas eu reverti. Evidentemente tu gostas mais de vírgulas do que eu (eu tenho consciência que omito vírgulas que a gramática considera, acho, obrigatórias). Mas a questão fundamental foi no último parágrafo, "em relação **a** *pescadinha*" e "devido **a** confusão", em que eu quero mesmo só a preposição ***a***. Imagino que isto para ti seja uma questão cerebral; para mim é figadal. No meu sotaque pronuncia-se ***a*** diferentemente de ***à***, de maneira que eu escolho instintivamente seguindo o ouvido. (Continua)

Comment: Mas sou coerente. Também usaria ***de*** e não ***da:*** "no caso **de** *pescadinha de rabo na boca*" (por me referir à expressão, e não ao bicho mesmo); "apareceu em resultado **de** confusão".

Comment: Sem problemas, minhas edições são sempre meras sugestões. Peço até desculpas, para ser sincero, ainda tenho dificuldades de distinguir o que é regionalismo do que é _""""gramaticalmente incorreto""""_ (espero ter posto aspas suficientes), mas estou melhorando. No português brasileiro, o acento grave não causa mudança sonora. Em relação às vírgulas, é um reflexo do meu déficit de atenção e deste lamentável fundo branco a arder minha vista. A gramática normativa considera muitos casos de vírgula como _opcionais_, mas fica meu pedido de usá-las mais frequentemente que o estritamente necessário.

Comment: @Ramon, comigo não te safas. Eu uso-as, as vírgulas, menos que o gramaticalmente prescrito (aversão adquirida talvez nos meus dez anos em Inglaterra). Eu sabia que *a* e *à* têm o mesmo som no Brasil (daí dizer que a distinção era cerebral). Em Portugal podemos confundir *há* e *à* (*à muito tempo*) mas não estes com *a* (preposição ou artigo).

Comment: Curioso que cites a língua inglesa. Também sou - injustamente - acusado de _abusar_ de meus poderes de edição para inserir vírgulas em posts alheios no SE vegetariano. Já tivemos, por lá, a discussão sobre a [vírgula de Oxford](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-01/enhanced/webdr03/15/13/enhanced-buzz-19599-1389811749-10.jpg). Vou evitá-las de agora em diante.

Answer (score 4):

A maioria da população usa "círculo vicioso" como expressão que descreve tal fenômeno, e **o uso popular consagra**. Uma vez que, no que se refere a expressões idiomáticas, o conceito de certo/errado não é regido por normas gramaticais mas sim pelo uso popular, se a maioria da população passar a dizer "ciclo vicioso", essa será a forma correta. Na maioria das línguas latinas usa-se a mesma expressão e a forma adotada é "círculo vicioso".  Um fenômeno interessante, no entanto, vem ocorrendo na língua inglesa. Veja abaixo o [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vicious%20circle%2Cvicious%20cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvicious%20circle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvicious%20cycle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvicious%20circle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvicious%20cycle%3B%2Cc0) comparatico do uso das duas formas através dos tempos. [image]

Notem que desde a segunda metade do século passado o termo "vicious circle" vem dando lugar ao termo "vicious cycle".  Embora o primeiro ainda seja mais comum, é bem possível que tradutores estejam introduzindo o segundo, vicious cycle, na língua portuguesa.  É lamentável que a língua portuguesa ainda não esteja disponível no ngram, mas vemos que em [espanhol](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%2Cciclo%20vicioso&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc%C3%ADrculo%20vicioso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cciclo%20vicioso%3B%2Cc0) usa-se "círculo vicioso" e que o termo "ciclo vicioso" é praticamente inexistente.

[image]

Respondendo de forma mais direta à tua pergunta, não se pode dizer que "ciclo vicioso" é errado.  Simplesmente não é idiomático, e pouco se ouve. As expressões idiomáticas são criadas e/ou adotadas pelos falantes de uma língua e, frequentemente, são modificadas. Discutir se deveríamos usar "ciclo" ao invés de "círculo", fica mais no terreno da filosofia e não no estudo da língua em si. O modo pelo qual o povo cria expressões idiomáticas não segue necessariamente uma lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Embora haja acima explicações e raciocínios brilhantes, penso que falta uma sutileza sobre essa discussão: "ciclo" e "círculo" são, basicamente, sinônimos. Ambas têm origem no grego "Kyklos" e para alguns casos usamos uma em detrimento da outra e nem diferença notamos: Na palavra "triciclo" usamos "tri" para denotar "três" e "ciclo" para denotar as rodas, objetos circulares que caracterizam o veículo. Fossem essas palavras tão distintas quanto dão a entender os comentários acima, diríamos sem nenhuma estranheza "tricírculo".

Answer (score -1):

Não se diz *ciclo vicioso*, mas sim *circulo vicioso*. Acredito que *ciclo* derivou simplesmente da oralidade, por soar próximo do termo *círculo*. As distinções que se procurarem vão sempre bater nas diferenças intrínsecas entre  os dois termos.

Comment: A pergunta existe para entender o "porquê", de forma devidamente justificada e sem teorias pessoais. Esta resposta apresenta aquilo que diria um dicionário, mas sem o devido fundamento para tal. Aliás, já ao mencionar "diferenças intrínsecas entre os dois temos", seria de esperar que a resposta dissesse quais, tendo em conta que a pergunta se apresenta como contra-argumento.

Comment: Ou seja: porquê? Diz-se assim e não assado, OK, mas qual é a justificação?

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando o **Áurelio**:

1. *Vicioso:* Que tem vício
2. *Vício:* Defeito grave, Costume nocivo, Prática irresistível de mal hábito.
3. *Ciclo:* Série de fenômenos sucessivos numa ordem determinada, Sequência de fenômenos que se renovam periodicamente
4. *Círculo:* Região limitada por uma circunferência, Linha circular
5. *Circular:* em forma de círculo.
6. *Circunferência:* Lugar geométrico equidistante de um ponto fixo.

Então, a definição de ***Ciclo Vicioso*** seria:

> Série (ou Sequência) de fenômenos sucessivos que periodicamente levam ao Vício.

Algo que está em um *Cíclo Vicioso* realiza ações/movimentos diferentes, mas em *determinado* momento entra em uma série de ações/movimentos que levam ao vício.

Ex: Uma pessoa com problemas de vício está em um *ciclo vicioso*, quando volta ao vício apenas (geralmente): depois de um longo período de abstinência, ou por reencontrar o grupo de "amigos" próximos que estimulam a pratica o vício (realiza várias atividades diferentes, mas depois de um certo tempo ou dos parceiros envolvidos, volta o vício).

E a definição de ***Círculo Vicioso*** seria:

> Região onde acontece o vício.

Algo que está em um *Círculo Vicioso* está dentro de uma região/situação de onde não consegue sair.

Ex: Uma pessoa com problemas de vício está em um *círculo vicioso*, quando não consegue fazer outra coisa diferente que não permita a prática do ato vicioso (só realiza atividades onde o vício acontece).

Comment: Receio que o raciocínio principal desta resposta não esteja correto: uma expressão pode passar a ter um significado especial por si, que não estará necessariamente em perfeita concordância com a combinação dos significados dos termos. Não esquecer também que, em alguns contextos, "círculo" é uma metáfora para "ciclo" e que por vezes substitui "circunferência".

Comment: @E_net4 você está sugerindo que eu tenha como base para minha resposta metáfora e subjetividade ?

Comment: Não, pelo contrário: que juntar os significados das duas palavras presentes na expressão "ciclo vicioso" (ou "círculo vicioso") para formar o significado da expressão é uma falácia. Dando um exemplo parecido, não podemos definir "febre amarela" como sendo uma febre desta cor. Contudo, esta resposta começou precisamente a seguir tal raciocínio, ignorando o próprio motivo histórico para se chamar "círculo vicioso".

Comment: definição da Fiocruz: Febre Amarela: ... icterícia (olhos e pele amarelados). O raciocínio deles também está errado ?

Answer (score -2):

Caríssimos, uma opinião modesta. A confusão gerada deve-se ao facto de, regra geral, quem opina sobre letras não ter conhecimentos científicos. A versão aristotélica circulo vicioso faz todo o sentido e vai continuar a ser usada quando nos referimos a eventos estáticos. Se o assunto em causa envolver alguma dinâmica, como no caso da analogia da quebra de rendimento das famílias, aí o termo correto (as ciberdúvidas da RTP que me desculpem) será ciclo vicioso. Será errado usar o termo circulo porque não tem nada a ver com o fenómeno. Quando regressamos ao ponto inicial já estamos com menos rendimento. Portanto não estamos nas mesmas condições. Quem fez as cadeiras de "física geral" ou "análise um" compreende perfeitamente este argumento.